# Asymptotic equivalence of the survival function of a standard Gaussian

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, survival, probability-inequalities

My statistics teacher told us the following asymptotic result:
$X \sim N(0,1) $
$$ P(X > u) \underset{u \rightarrow +\infty}{\sim} \frac{1}{u} \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right). $$

Do you know how to demonstrate this (or if there is a mistake?)
Thank you.

Comment: Hi. What did you do to (dis)prove the proposition? Show us your attempts. Thanks.

Comment: I was only able to find an upper bound by the Chernoff method.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=mills%20ratio&searchOn=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you gave is close (you missed the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$) to the correct asymptotic behavior of the survival function of standard normal distribution:
\begin{align*}
1 - \Phi(x) \sim \frac{1}{x}\varphi(x), \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ are CDF and PDF of standard normal random variable respectively.

$(1)$ is a corollary of the inequality (for fixed $x > 0$)
\begin{align*}
(x^{-1} - x^{-3})\varphi(x) < 1 - \Phi(x) < x^{-1}\varphi(x). \tag{2}
\end{align*}

To prove $(2)$, notice the obvious inequality:
\begin{align*}
(1 - 3t^{-4})\varphi(t) < \varphi(t) < (1 + t^{-2})\varphi(t), \; t > x. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Integrating three expressions above from $x$ to $\infty$ yields $(2$) -- note that each term in $(2)$ is the primitive function of each term in $(3)$ times $-1$.